# bash loop for checking service and network connection

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

I want to start omxplayer, check if there is the process is up, check if there is internet connection start with play a streaming, if there is not play a local loop, meanwhile try to check if the internet connection is up, if there is internet connection stop local file and play streaming video.
I write this... any suggestion?
Thanks

````bsh
#!/bin/bash
killall -9 omxplayer.bin
SERVICE='omxplayer'
while true; do
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
then
echo "Running" # sleep 5
else
sleep 5
log=log_file_pette.txt
# create log file or overrite if already present
printf "Log File Streaming- " >> $log

# append date to log file
date >> $log

# send email with date restart
echo `date` | mailx -s "Subject: Start streaming Ad" miamail@mia.com
# if there is no internet and no ping
if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com >/dev/null
then
killall -9 omxplayer.bin
$SERVICE -o alsa https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8 &
else
# create log file or overrite if already present
printf "Log File Local- " >> $log

# append date to log file
date >> $log
killall -9 omxplayer.bin
$SERVICE -o alsa looptv.mp4 
sleep 5
fi
fi
done
```
````

Comment: If `miamail@mia.com` is a real email address, then I suggest to redact it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use indentation to make the flow of logic easier to see

With indentation added to the original code,
it's a lot easier to understand the branches of the logic:

```
killall -9 omxplayer.bin
SERVICE='omxplayer'
while true; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
        echo "Running" # sleep 5
    else
        sleep 5
        log=log_file_pette.txt
        # create log file or overrite if already present
        printf "Log File Streaming- " >> $log

        # append date to log file
        date >> $log

        # send email with date restart
        echo `date` | mailx -s "Subject: Start streaming Ad" foo@example.com
        # if there is no internet and no ping
        if ping -q -c 1 -W 1 google.com >/dev/null
        then
            killall -9 omxplayer.bin
            $SERVICE -o alsa https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8 &
        else
            # create log file or overrite if already present
            printf "Log File Local- " >> $log

            # append date to log file
            date >> $log
            killall -9 omxplayer.bin
            $SERVICE -o alsa looptv.mp4 
            sleep 5
        fi
    fi
done
```

#### Use functions to avoid duplicated logic

This snippet appears twice, with one word replaced:

> ```
> # create log file or overrite if already present
> printf "Log File Streaming- " >> $log
>
> # append date to log file
> date >> $log
> ```

It would be good to create a helper function for it, with the changing part a variable:

```
log_with_label() {
    local label=$1
    echo "Log File $label- $(date)" >> "$log"
}
```

Then you can call this with `log_with_label "Streaming"` and `log_with_label "Local"`.

Even the simple `killall -9 omxplayer.bin` would be good in a helper function:

```
kill_player() {
    killall -9 omxplayer.bin
}
```

#### The comments... are lying...

Some of the comments are confusing, because they don't tell the truth.

No sleeping happens here:

> ```
> echo "Running" # sleep 5
> ```

The file will not be overwritten here. This will append to the file if exists:

> ```
> # create log file or overrite if already present
> printf "Log File Streaming- " >> $log
> ```

#### Use double-quotes around variables in shell commands

Instead of these:

> ```
> if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
> printf "Log File Streaming- " >> $log
> $SERVICE -o alsa https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8 &
> ```

write like this:

```
if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep "$SERVICE" > /dev/null
printf "Log File Streaming- " >> "$log"
"$SERVICE" -o alsa https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/playlist.m3u8 &
```

#### Avoid deeply nested code

Looking at this code:

> ```
> while true; do
>     if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
>     then
>         echo "Running" # sleep 5
>     else
>
>         # ... many, many lines here....
>
>     fi
> done
> ```

By the time the I reach the `fi`, I don't remember what the base condition was.
It would be good to reduce the nesting with a `continue` in the `if` branch.
(I'm wondering if you wanted to put a `sleep 5` in there, in code, instead of a comment...)

```
while true; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
        echo "Running" # sleep 5
        continue
    fi

    # ... many, many lines here....

done
```

#### Use [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

shellcheck.net is a that finds bugs in your shell scripts.
It's good to fix all the violations raised by it.